# How can I create the Tag on an EC2 instance using the .Net API

Tags: .net, amazon-ec2

If I set up a tag on the Amazon website directly I can access it in the runningInstance.Tag property. Is there any way to set it up when I start the instance using the RunInstancesResponse?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where the variable ec2 is an instance of Amazon.EC2.AmazonEC2

```
 public RunInstancesResult RunInstances()
        {
            RunInstancesRequest request;
            RunInstancesResponse response;
            RunInstancesResult result;

            request = new RunInstancesRequest();

            request
                .WithInstanceType(InstanceType)
                .WithImageId(ImageId)
                .WithKeyName(KeyName)
                .WithPlacement(new Placement() {AvailabilityZone = AvailabilityZone})
                .WithMaxCount(1)
                .WithMinCount(1)
                .WithSecurityGroup(SecurityGroups);

            response = ec2.RunInstances(request);

            InstanceId = response.RunInstancesResult.Reservation.RunningInstance[0].InstanceId;

            var trequest = new CreateTagsRequest();

            trequest.WithResourceId(InstanceId);
            trequest.WithTag(new Tag[] {
                    new Tag { Key = "#Name", Value = ServerTag },
                    new Tag { Key = "Hosts", Value = "prod data restored"}
            });

            var tresponse = ec2.CreateTags(trequest);

            return response.RunInstancesResult;
        }
```

Comment: This way has a potential problem, I ever encountered an "instance id not found" exception in calling CreateTagsRequest, but the instance was sure started, so maybe sometime the instance is "invisible" right after starting it.

Comment: You should use withTagSpecifications in the RunInstancesRequest to make it atomic